# Why does vector pointers takes so much memory?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, boolean

I'm working on a project where I need to be as mean as possible regarding the memory usage. I'm trying to calculate the grand total size of a `vector<bool>` of size `32` in the example:

```
vector<bool> v(32);
cout << "sizeof: " << sizeof(v) << endl;
cout << "size: " << v.size() << endl;
cout << "capacity: " << v.capacity() << endl;
cout << "max_size: " << v.max_size() << endl;
```

which gives me:

```
sizeof: 40                     <- 40 byte? wtf?
size: 32                       <- hoping an element takes up 1 bit
                                  (instead of the usual 1 byte for booleans)
                                  this should take around 32 bit memory
capacity: 64                   <- I guess this is because minimum size is
                                  1 integer = 64 bit
max_size: 9223372036854775744  <- relevant somehow?
```

on my 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 machine. So I thought I could calculate the memory like so:

```
40 * 8 + 64 * 1 = 384 bit = 48 byte
```

So according to this calculation most of the memory is spent for the vector object of size `32`. My question is why does a `vector` object need to use so much memory? And also are there any mistakes in my calculation? How can I be more efficient without doing bitwise manipulations myself for vector sizes around `32`?

Comment: Don't see any pointers in example you showed.

Comment: `vector<bool>` is a special case and has special treatment.

Comment: Quite a few misconceptions... 'size()==32' means that you have 32 bits, which is correct. 'capacity()==64' means that you can add 32 more, and is probably unrelated to the size of an *integer* (`int` is usually 32bits in most platforms). Note that what you call *vector pointer* is really the *vector object*

Comment: @AlokSave ahh right, but I'm not sure what to call it.

Comment: Vectors hold more than one pointer (it won't work otherwise!).

Comment: @gokcehan: It is a instance of `std::vector<bool>` not a pointer.

Comment: Well I thought to have a little dig through the g++ implementation. For normal vectors, it contains 3 pointers: start of data, end of data, end of available space. And `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` is indeed 24. Now `std::vector<bool>` is a bit special to take account of storing each `bool` in a single bit. However I haven't yet been able to make any sense of the header file...

Comment: Have you tried `std::bitset<32>`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/88934/14065

Comment: @LokiAstari that's what I'm trying atm, thanks. I will accept an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of your `std::vector` is actually fixed at compile-time, then it may make sense to use a `std::array` instead; an array does not have *any* overhead (there is padding though).

However, in the very specific case of `bool`, you should consider `std::bitset`! A `bitset` is parameterized by its size and packs the `bool` as to be as efficient as possible. It's not exactly as memory efficient as a packed array (than you would write yourself) because it keeps a count of the toggled bits.

Demo at [liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/LiOj3%240):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::vector<bool> vec(32);
   std::array<bool, 32> arr;
   std::array<uint8_t, 4> packed;
   std::bitset<32> bs;

   std::cout << "vector: " << sizeof(vec) + vec.capacity()/8 << "\n";
   std::cout << "array : " << sizeof(arr) << "\n";
   std::cout << "packed: " << sizeof(packed) << "\n";
   std::cout << "bitset: " << sizeof(bs) << "\n";
}
```

Gives:

```
vector: 48
array : 32
packed: 4
bitset: 8
```

Where `packed` clearly is the most efficient container, but `bitset` provides a ready-made one for a quite low cost (just as much space as a pointer on 64 bits machines).

Comment: this is really helpful, can you elaborate on packed? how does it work?

Comment: @gokcehan: it work manually, the idea is that you only need 32 bits (so actually a `uint32_t` would be enough) so you create an array of 32 bits (in general, `ceil(N/CHAR_BITS)`) and then use bitmasking operations to query/set the bits. Obviously, it's a bit of work to write the get/set methods, but bitwise manipulations are fairly well documented on the net so you should not have any trouble... you just end up reimplementing `bitset` though (albeit, with a lower memory footprint at the cost of no O(1) "count" method); it's your call what's the best in your situation.

Comment: ahh I see. I had already been using `[]` operations all around my code and `bitset` didn't complain about it when I switched to it. I suppose I could overload `[]` somehow but that's quite a bit of work for me. Also I realized I'm gonna need `c++0x` for arrays which I better not so I will stick with the bitsets for now. I will accept your answer since it's the most comprehensive one, thanks..

Answer (score 4):

Those 40 bytes are administrative overhead. Among other things, a `vector` has to keep track of its `size` and `capacity` (that's two `size_t`s worth of bytes gone already), and very importantly, a pointer to the actual data!

The actual data kept by the vector is allocated on the heap by the default vector allocator, its memory consumption is not included in the result of `sizeof`.

Comment: hmm, kind of makes sense. any advice how to make it more efficient?

Comment: What is "inefficient" in this? You could of course have a class that store the sizes in 32 bits, limiting the maximum number of elements stored to 4 billion, and saving 8 bytes. Unless you are having LOTS and LOTS of vectors, I suspect that's not really worth doing.

Comment: @gokcehan as I mentioned in my answer, if you know the maximum number of bits you need to store, you can use `std::bitset` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(v)` is getting the size of `v`'s structure, not the size of `v`'s data. It's like doing:

```
struct S { int* x };

S s;
s.x = new int[10000];

sizeof(s); // only the size of int* (it doesn't/can't check how much data is allocated)
```

As for why `std::vector<bool>` might have a larger structure size than, say, `std::vector<int>`, remember that the `bool` version is specialized. It's got to have some extra members for bitwise record keeping.

Comment: I have already tried to add the size of data it points to the total by doing `+ 64 * 1`

Answer (score 1):

- `v.size()` returns the number of elements that can be stored in the `vector`. Not memory-size-directly-related
- `v.capacity()` returns the amount of memory cells allocated for the vector. Vectors allocate some memory in advance, but not all can be accessed initially. Not-memory-size-directly-related
- `sizeof(v)` is getting the size in bytes of the structure itself. I suppose some pointers go here. As well as the size variable etc.

If you want to get the memory the elements of the vector are taking probably this would be the closest expression: `v.size() * sizeof(v[0])`

Comment: if some memory is allocated already, shouldn't I be interested in that as well?

Comment: @gokcehan Depends on what you are trying to measure. Generally my answer would be no, because this is just constant overhead - nevermind how many elements you have in the vector you have the overhead of 40 bytes

Comment: I tried a few different numbers and vector<bool> is growing linearly as you said instead of the usual exponential growth of vectors. It's kind of interesting to me because I feel like it would effect the complexity analysis of amortized cost of pushing an element to the vector.

Comment: @gokcehan "exponential growth of vectors" what do you exactly mean by that? what test do you do?

Comment: I mean the capacity growing like `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 ..` when I keep adding elements but it turned out I was doing the test wrongly so `vector<bool>` capacity is also increasing exponentially like `64, 128, 256, 512 ..`.

Comment: @gokcehan this is not depending on the type you store - always the size will be at most twice as much as the stored elements

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of the g++ implementation I can find the following members:

vector inherits from
      _Bvector_impl _M_impl;

From the inherited _Bvector_impl

```
_Bit_iterator   _M_start;   16 bytes
_Bit_iterator   _M_finish;  16 bytes
_Bit_type*  _M_end_of_storage;  8 bytes
```

This sums up to 40 bytes.

_Bit_iterator contains

```
_M_offset, an unsigned int: 8 bytes
_M_p,      a pointer 8 bytes.
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the price you pay for a dynamically re-sizable structure. What's returned by `sizeof(v)` is actually just the overhead for the vector to keep track of the dynamically allocated memory where it stores its data. The space for storing the data is not included in that number.

If you know the number of items at compile time, you can use `std::bitset` instead. `std::bitset` actually will use 1 bit per boolean you store (rounded up to the word size it uses) without the overhead of `std::vector`.

Comment: I tried and bitset takes only 8 bytes. I guess that should be the minimum since I need to point to data somehow with a pointer. thanks, +1.